# how can we call SQL stored procedure in Entity framework 6.1.3?

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

We tried to add SP through a model, but after adding SP into the model, the following code is generated and is getting build-in errors. We aren't able to build the project. Please find the below code (Context.cs file) for reference. Please help us.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Usp_GetAppUsers_Result> Usp_GetAppUsers(string displayName, string userName, string userPassword, Nullable<int> orgBranchID, string activeStatus)
        {
            var displayNameParameter = displayName != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("DisplayName", displayName) :
                new ObjectParameter("DisplayName", typeof(string));

            var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
                new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

            var userPasswordParameter = userPassword != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", userPassword) :
                new ObjectParameter("UserPassword", typeof(string));

            var orgBranchIDParameter = orgBranchID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("OrgBranchID", orgBranchID) :
                new ObjectParameter("OrgBranchID", typeof(int));

            var activeStatusParameter = activeStatus != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ActiveStatus", activeStatus) :
                new ObjectParameter("ActiveStatus", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Usp_GetAppUsers_Result>("Usp_GetAppUsers", displayNameParameter, userNameParameter, userPasswordParameter, orgBranchIDParameter, activeStatusParameter);
        }
```

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<DAL.Usp_GetAppUsers_Result>(string, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ExecutionOptions, params System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some invalid arguments Context.cs 56 20 DataAccessLayer.               we are getting this error.

Comment: What version of .net are your running? I presume you are using .net < 4.0

Comment: we are using VS 2012

Comment: That isn't a version of .net. Please find out which Framework you are compiling against.

Comment: we are using .net 4.5 framework

Comment: I looks like you are using an old version of the edmx to cs T4 templates, upgrade to the `EF 6.x DbContext Generator`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx

Comment: Yes.. now we can able to build the solution and can able to retrieve table objects. But while accessing SP, getting the error below... The FunctionImport 'sp_GetUsers' could not be found in the container 'AdminModelEntities'.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The FunctionImport 'sp_GetUsers' could not be found in the container 'AdminModelEntities'

Comment: we gone through some links in google and resolved this issue, but we did some changes in context.cs file manually. We replaced 'ObjectParameter' with 'SqlParameter' , '((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction' with '(this).Database.SqlQuery' and return type also changed as List<> instead of 'ObjectResult<>'. Could you please tell us, is there any easy way to fixed this issue.

Comment: Without seeing your entire solution, that is difficult. Not to mention, it is my belief that there should never be any SPROCs in EF. IE stop using SPROCs.

Comment: Ok. I understood what you are saying. But we had requirement like SProcs with EF. Let me try is there any solution. Let me know if you find any better solution. thank you.